# Can not ping two endsystems each connected to a separate router

Tags: networking, router, routing, ping

I have two routers and two end systems configured as shown below:
[image: figure]

Also I have configured the routing table correctly, I believe, like,

```
On Router2:

Destination IP: 192.168.1.0
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.28.1 (nexthop)
```

```
On Router1:

Destination IP: 192.168.0.0
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.28.2 (nexthop)
```

I am able to reach `router 2` from `router 1` but not the end systems present in that LAN, that is, I can not ping both the end systems across the routers.

Comment: You have both routers marked as **Router 1**  It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Does the other PC receive your ping packets? Does it attempt to respond? Do any of the systems (the other PC, or any of the routers) have firewalls active? In particular, Windows hosts have a firewall by default, and since you're labelling the router interfaces as "internal" and "external", this implies it's the kind of router that'll have a firewall blocking ext→int packets by default.

Comment: There is an error in your diagram, but i expect your problem is either NAT, or a lack of routes on router 1 and router 2 or both.

Comment: @RohitGupta Apologies for the error in the diagram, I have corrected it now. PC2 is connected to Router2.

Comment: @user1686 I see. I have firewall turned on, on both the PCs. The other PC is not receiving the ping packets. Always says `request timed out`

Comment: @davidgo I am not sure I fully understood your answer. The router 1 and router 2 are connected via Ethernet. Do you mean that I need to have multiple paths/routes from router 1 to router 2? NAT seems logical. How to resolve it?

Comment: @Koushik: "Request timed out" can mean either that it's not receiving the packets **or** that it's not responding **or** that you're not receiving the responses that it's sending. You need to check all three possibilities. Install a packet capture tool on PC2 (e.g. Wireshark) and check.

Comment: @user1686: Ok I disabled the firewall on both the PCs and just checked it with wireshark. It says “no response found!”

Comment: Does it at least show the _incoming request_ on PC2?

Comment: No it doesn’t. Also I cannot reach the router 1 from PC2.

Comment: I’m able to do it now. There’s an option called **SPI firewall** (Stateful Packet Inspection) in the router security settings that is enabled by default. Disabling it will expose all the computers on the LAN to the outside world. 
However I am not able to ping the routers from PCs. PC1 to PC2 and vice-versa is working.

Comment: Define the netmasks as `255.255.0.0`, then all computers should be reachable.